# Specific order stopping remote service and proceed once it is stopped

Tags: batch-file, windows-services, windows-server

am new to batch file writing. A bat script must do the following. I have to follow this specific order. Any help on the would be useful to me.

1. First stop a service say x on server a, and another server y on server b.
2. Should wait for these both to be stopped and then stop another service on these two servers.
3. Delete few directories in each server. (different paths)
4. Same gets repeated for few more servers.
5. And should start the services in reverse order that of which is used to stop these.

So i am stuck here. I want to check if the service is completely stopped, and do further actions.

```
:Check
 SC \\**** query **** | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED" >NUL >> Result.txt 
 IF errorlevel == 0 
 GOTO Waiter
 else GOTO P1 

:Waiter 
timeout /t 10 
GOTO Check
```

Comment: Google is your friend! This question looks too broad on the first look and all those things can be found seperately explained in various questions on SO. I am sure about that! If that helps nothing, try to get as far as possible for you and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Such things should be an [edit] to your question :)